# Once I can list users using XMPP, how do I implement chat among those users?

Tags: iphone, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I have configured the XMPP framework in my iPhone app.  I am able to access my ejabberd and I can list online users.

Now I want to implement chat using this XMPP among those users.  How could I implement this? What method could I use for that?

Comment: I have worked with the XMPP framework a while back and remember that they have a good documentation as well as some sample code. Have you read the samples? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: hi, thanks for your response . Yes , I have read those samples and also have implemented. Its working great. now I just want to implement chat among those users. I could not send or receive messages between them.I am stuck here.

Comment: here is a good example of XMPP chat refer it http:[//code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/checkout](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/checkout)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ejabberd and a module like XML RPC, you could probably use the `send_message_chat <from> <to> <body>` function.